# Azure AD B2C Custom Policy

Tags: data-binding, policy, azure-ad-b2c

I have implemented sign in/signup policies using Azure AD B2C custom policy.
I came across two problems while doing this:

1. Is there a method so I can add a button to sign in page which redirects on click?
   Or can I add a hyperlink in HTML document and call the policy to it?
2. Is it possible to display what we type on a textbox in another label like in AJAX?
   As custom policies are created using XML, can I use data binding for this?

Comment: Can you provide screenshots or further clarify what you want to achieve. It's not quite clear.

Comment: Is it possible to modify the custom policy to by adding scripts to make content in one textbox visible on another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**At this point, Azure AD B2C pages only support HTML/CSS customization and not any JavaScript-based modifications.**

I can't think of any other way for you to achieve either of the two behaviors your described other than using client side JavaScript.

You can support this ask and stay up to date on its progress by voting for it in the Azure AD B2C feedback forum: [Add support for JavaScript inside the custom UI branding page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15493536-add-support-for-javascript-inside-the-custom-ui-br)

Comment: Update: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples