# Azure Active Directory B2C Custom Policy

Tags: javascript, policy, azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to modify the custom policy by adding scripts to make content in one textbox visible on another?

Can we use Ajax or two way data binding if so?

I have referred the content given under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview
so far.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**At this point, Azure AD B2C pages only support HTML/CSS customization and not any JavaScript-based modifications.**

I can't think of any other way for you to achieve either of the two behaviors your described other than using client side JavaScript.

You can support this ask and stay up to date on its progress by voting for it in the Azure AD B2C feedback forum: [Add support for JavaScript inside the custom UI branding page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15493536-add-support-for-javascript-inside-the-custom-ui-br)

Comment: You are busted at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics :)
It tells you replicated the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45707516/929902